# Can anyone identify this dragonfly spotted outside of Boston, MA?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can somebody identify this dragonfly please? It was seen about 15 miles west of Boston.

[image]

Comment: *This* dragonfly? I see two of them, one eating the other.

Comment: Yes...I interrupted lunch for the greed darner. Not sure what the other one is, you really can't see it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a male [Green Darner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_darner).

Pretty common in general, especially in the US.